# Changing the URL path of route provider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement URL route provider in Angularjs. I have added the following code :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');

$stateProvider

.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/app',
  templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/app.html'
})

.state('app1',{
  abstract:true,
  url: '/app1',
  templateURL: 'views/tmpl/app1.html'
 })

.state('app2',{
  abstract: true,
  url: '/app2',
  templateURL: 'views/tmpl/app2.html'
})
//dashboard
.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/dashboard.html',
  resolve: {
    plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load([
        'scripts/vendor/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.min.css',
        'scripts/vendor/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.min.css'
      ]);
    }]
  }
})
```

The issue i am facing is that whenever i try to access the state app1 or app2 , it redirects to 'otherwise' .  I don't know where i am doing wrong. Please share your views.

Comment: because you mentioned those state as `abstract:true` you can;t have access them directly..

Comment: I have changed those state after you said. It redirects to the respective page but unable to load the contents. for ex, in app1.html, i am just printing 'HELLO' . Thought the URL is getting changed, the page is not loading.('HELLO' is not getting displayed)